# ANTLR TypeScript target: TokenStream.d.ts prototypes for `getHiddenTokensToLeft/Right()` don't match implementations

Tags: typescript, antlr4

The declared method signatures for `TokenStream#getHiddenTokensToLeft` and `#getHiddenTokensToRight` in [TokenStream.d.ts](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4/TokenStream.d.ts) take strings for their second (`channelName`) parameters, but `TokenStream`'s only stock subclass, [BufferedTokenStream](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/8188dc5388dfe9246deb9b6ae507c3693fd55c3f/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4/BufferedTokenStream.js#L301), doesn't resolve those channel names; it's expecting integer channel IDs.

I agree with the type file that it'd be great if `BufferedTokenStream` *did* resolve named channels for us out of the box, but I think we're both disappointed (at least for now), unless I'm missing something?

```js
export declare class TokenStream {
    // ....
    getHiddenTokensToLeft(tokenIndex: number, channelName?: string): Token[];
    getHiddenTokensToRight(tokenIndex: number, channelName?: string): Token[];
    // ...
}
```

```
lexer grammar QueryLexer;

channels {
    CHANN_WHITESPACE,
    CHANN_COMMENTS
}

// ...

WS:   [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(CHANN_WHITESPACE) ;
SL_COMMENTS: '//' .*? '\n' -> channel(CHANN_COMMENTS) ;
BL_COMMENTS: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(CHANN_COMMENTS) ;
```

Always returns `null`:

```js
// `tokenStream` is a `CommonTokenStream`
const comments = this.tokenStream.getHiddenTokensToLeft(startTokenIdx, "CHANN_COMMENTS");
```

Behaves as expected:

```js
/* @ts-ignore */ 
const comments = this.tokenStream.getHiddenTokensToLeft(startTokenIdx, 3);
```

Comment: [Those declarations](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/8188dc5388dfe9246deb9b6ae507c3693fd55c3f/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4/TokenStream.d.ts#L12-L13) need to be fixed. Please create an Issue for it to be corrected. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues. Honestly, these declarations should not even be TokenStream, but in BufferedTokenStream. That's how it's done in the Java and CSharp targets. Or if it's supposed to be declared in TokenStream, fix the Java and CSharp ports. It's intolerable.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check; [issue opened](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/4182).